# First sheet is empty or corrupt after write in R

Tags: r, excel

Hello I use this code for write data in first sheet to another sheet. In result first sheet was empty or corrupt because show error excel try restore but sheet is empty.
In shortly:

1 sheet write 2 sheet

Result now: 1 sheet empty, 2 sheet have data from write

Result (Which i want): 1 sheet not empty 2 sheet have data frow write

```
   wb <- loadWorkbook("file.xlsx")
          writeData(wb, sheet = "List 5", result_table, colNames = F)
          saveWorkbook(wb,"file.xlsx",overwrite = T)
```

Comment: Hi @John, it would be easier to help you if your problem was broken down and reproducible to extent possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451

Comment: @Bulat Short i don't want that my sheet which data not be empty. Can you help me plz

Comment: Your code only writes to one sheet: "List 5". One would not expect two sheets to be written. You could add another `writeData` call to write data to another sheet.